# Elasticsearch and dynamic aliases

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, kibana, fluentd

I use Elasticsearch 2.3 with fluentd/logstash and kibana and have fluentd/logstash writing to the index logstash-YYYY.MM.dd

But because mistakes happen and I would like to be able to re-index my data I would instead like to write to the alias logstash-YYYY.MM.dd-alias.

This is what I can do:

- Create an index with index template and auto-created the alias using
  `{ aliases: {"{index}-alias":{}}}`
- Write to the alias for the rest of the day

The problem is: Let's say it is 2016-04-12. On the new day, the index "logstash-2016.04.13" does not exist and hence neither its alias "logstash-2016.04.13-alias". So instead of creating both, Elasticsearch creates "logstash-2016.04.13-alias" and its alias "logstash-2016.04.13-alias-alias"

- Possible solution: Have a cronjob running to create the index 5 minutes before midnight.

Downside: Cronjob server can go down. Timezone issues can occur. Other errors lead to more errors.

Is there any other way to manage writing to an alias using a date format without having to create the index+alias pair beforehand?

Comment: IIRC, you can't create an alias until the index exists, so the cron idea wouldn't work well.

Comment: But when I create the index (```curl -XPUT .../logstash-YYYY.MM.dd```) before midnight and the index template defines the alias, then I would create both at the same time, wouldn't I?

Comment: If you forced the index to exist, then you should be OK.